# ListBox, Select index change

Tags: c#, list, listbox

One for visits and one for pickups, When a user adds either of the visits or pickups to the list it is also added into a list box for showing to the user.

My question is when I clicked on the item inside the list box eg Indexchanged, I would like it to open the new GUI that relates to either Visits or delivery's, So if they click on a Visit it opens the visit form as shown bellow in my code, but how can I get it to differentiate between the lists so that It knows which form to open up?

```
 private void lstVisits_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Allow the user to click on the listbox to open a visit
        //This event is called after the user has clicked on the list
        int index = lstVisits.SelectedIndex;
        //Get the index of the Visit that the user has clicked upon

        Visits selected = theList.getVisits(index);
        //Get the visits object from the list

        Visitsform.visits = selected;
        //Ensure that the appointment form references the selected visit

        Visitsform.ShowDialog();
        //Show the visits form

        updateList();
        //update the list as the user may have deleted the appointment
```

Comment: Where are Visits and Delivers stored? Do you have two listBoxes one for Visits and one for Delivers and or both are added to the same listBox?

Comment: They are two different lists, one class called List.cs for the Visit list and One Class called pickuplist.cs to store the deliverys, and they are both added into one list box

Comment: What is `theList`? And what method `getVisits(index)` does?

Comment: theList is the link from the form to the list object in the list class, and the getVisits(Index) method calls the getVisits() from the list which populates the listbox with the visits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If items from both lists are stored in the same listBox, then you could use something like this:

EDIT:If you want to get the objects from the listBox, then you should add them as objects to the listBox, for example:

```
Visits v = new Visit();
Pickups p = new Pickup();
lstVisits.Items.Add(v);
lstVisits.Items.Add(p);    


private void lstVisits_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (listBox1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    object o = listBox1.SelectedItems[0];
                    if (o is Visits)
                    {
                        Visits visit = (Visits)o;
                        Visitsform.visits = visit;
                        Visitsform.ShowDialog();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Deliveries delivery = (Deliveries)o;
                        Deliveriesform.visits = visit;
                        Deliveriesform.ShowDialog();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hey, So I tried this and it highlights the first line of the else statements and gives me the following error
Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Coursework_2.Pickups'.

Comment: You should be able to cast the object to its type if you add it like object. It seems like you add only the string for the object and you can't cast it. Override ToString method in your classes (Visits and Pickups) and fill the listBox with them. Then you will be able to cast them.

Comment: In the pickups class I have base.ToString, is this what you mean

Comment: nvm I did the override thing but I am still getting the same error as before

Comment: The edit explains how you should add your instances to the listBox

Comment: Thanks for all the help But I don't know this doesn't seem to be working, probably my fault since I have no idea what to do, 
I have been adding them like lstVisits.items.addrange(listOfPic.toArray())

Comment: I think I may just have to find another way like 2 listboxes or something

Comment: You shouldn't accept the answer if it not helps you. Maybe you should add more code to the question in order to be more clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: It did help me in some ways, Just not for my project, But it gave me a better understanding of it in general... Also I would add more code but I really dont know what to add, I  have like 3 GUI's 4 Classes and about 12buttons

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20079/discussion-between-tam-and-nikolad-nick)